# So what if a subset of $R$ is not a subspace $R$?

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

I'm trying to develop my conceptual understanding of vector spaces and subspaces.

Let $W$ be the set of all points $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$. These are the points in the first quadrant. The set of $W$ is *not* a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it is not closed under scalar multiplication. For example, $v=(1,1)$ lies in $W$, but its negative $(-1)v=-v=(-1,1)$ does not.

**My question is:** So what? The definition of a vector space seems arbitrary to me. Okay, so this set is not closed under scalar multiplication and is not a vector space, and thus not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Why is this meaningful? What is this telling me beyond the seemingly arbitrary definition of a vector space? Why would one need to identify such a distinction?

Comment: Are you looking for a *physics* answer to this question? Because there are lots of *math* answers and lots of *physics* answers.  The definition of a vector space is decidedly not arbitrary.  Solution sets to linear differential equations form a vector space. The state space of quantum mechanics is a vector space (with caveats that really it is *projective* space, but whatever). Linear algebra and vector spaces abound, and subspaces are relevant: e.g., in quantum mechanics, subspaces can correspond to values of conserved quantities.

Comment: The point is, this is a pretty broad question, I guess.

Comment: "The definition of a vector space seems arbitrary to me." Definitions **are always** arbitrary. You are free to define whatever you like. That is the whole point about definitions as opposed to theorems. "Why is this meaningful?" Because it is meaningful. "Why would one need to identify such a distinction?" Because it is more convenient to say "vector space" than always rattling down the axioms of a vector space. See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA .

Comment: If you travel throughout the world it seems useful to know whether or not you are in danger of falling off an edge.

Comment: A subspace is itself a vector space. If it isn't closed under scalar multiplication  then it isn't a vector space. This is an incredibly simple idea. Perhaps if you told us what you are trying to understand, we could make it more clear.

Comment: @oliver The definition of a vector space is not arbitrary nor are any in mathematics. The definitions are motivated by an attempt to abstract away properties of concrete things so that we can study them in a more general setting. If the definition of a vector space or any other structure seems arbitrary then it is probably the case that the reader of the definition doesn't have enough exposure to the motivating examples.

Comment: Are you familiar with group theory? . If yes then you must know that Vector spaces are groups under addition and hence each subspace must be a subgroup. It does not make sense to study every subset . Rather we focus on the subsets which preserve the structure of the whole space itself and hence the name subspace.  For exaple....in integers it does not make sense to talk about the subset $\{1,2\}$ and define addition in it. However if you take the subset of even integers then you can define addition.